# How to run a vue project from github

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to run this Vue project https://github.com/akumatus/FilterBuilder from Github on my local machine. Usually, I just clone the project and run 'npm install' but in this project, there is no package.json to fetch the dependencies from. I am still a vue.js beginner and trying to learn the language so was hoping to run the project on my local machine and play around with it.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this issue:

https://github.com/akumatus/FilterBuilder/issues/4

The author suggests to `checkout` the `demo` branch and then run the `npm install`

https://github.com/akumatus/FilterBuilder/tree/demo

Other than that, you could initiate blank vuejs project and add the components to your project, and import them:

```
import AndOr from './components/AndOr.vue'
import Rule from './components/Rule.vue'
```

and then

```
Vue.use('AndOr');
Vue.use('Rule');
```

before initiating the Vue app

After that, use the components according to the README file.

Comment: Thank you Niklaz, I will keep that in mind for future projects :)

Answer (score 0):

switch branch to *demo* and fetch , package.json is there ;)

Comment: Gosh ! That was so simple. Thank you, Saeed